# What #define flag indicates THUMB-2 instructions are available?

Tags: c, compiler-flags

I a version of some C code which I have optimized to use specific ARM THUMB-2 assembly instructions. I want the program to compile to use these instructions when they are available, and when they are not I want to compile the unoptimized branch.

What is the right `#ifdef` for this when using the ARM gcc compiler?

Comment: This is somethin *you* are telling the compiler (the target architecture/instruction set), not something the compiler can tell.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? If GCC, please see [target_clones](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) attribute which allows you to generate multiple versions of the code and to automatically select the best version during runtime. Probably you want two versions: -marm and -mthumb. In latter case GCC will define `__thumb2__` macro. You can check this with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 -dM -E -mthumb - < /dev/null  | grep -i thumb`.

Comment: @gudok, I literally was opening up stackoverflow to add that info. Thanks for being so quick to answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, and no. I agree that something like the Makefile does this, and I run the Makefile. However, that does not mean that I know what options the Makefile passes to the compiler. For instance, when compiling for Particle devices, there's a big "compile" button, which (happily) hides all the complexity from the end user.

Comment: @gudok thanks, that was exactly what I needed. If you make that an answer, I'll select it.